# How to manipulate json data in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

In a Jmeter Script, I need to process a http response e manipulate a json for send in next request, because actually this manipulation occurs in a Angular client.

My Http reponse:

```
[
   {
      "function":"nameA",
      "rast":"F1",
      "tag":"EE",
      "probs":"0,987"
   },
   {
      "function":"nameB",
      "rast":"F2",
      "tag":"SE",
      "probs":"0,852"
   },
   {
      "function":"nameC",
      "rast":"F3",
      "tag":"CE",
      "probs":"0,754"
   }
]
```

I need convert the result in json bellow to post in next request:

```
[
   {
      "function":"nameA",
      "rast":"F1",
      "type":{
         "name":"EE"
      },
      "id":"alpha"
   },
   {
      "function":"nameB",
      "rast":"F2",
      "type":{
         "name":"SE"
      },
      "id":"alpha"
   },
   {
      "function":"nameC",
      "rast":"F3",
      "type":{
         "name":"CE"
      },
      "id":"alpha"
   }
]
```

I filter the response with this JSON Extractor:

```
[*].["function", "rast", "tag"]
```

But now I need to solve other problems:

1. Add an `id` attribute (same for all functions)
2. Add an object with the name type.
3. Move the tag attribute into the object called `type`.
4. Rename the tag attribute to the `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the original JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).each { entry ->
       entry << [type: [name: entry.get('tag')]]
       entry.remove('tag')
       entry.remove('probs')
       entry.put('id', 'alpha')
   }
   def newJson = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
   log.info(newJson)
   ```
3. That's it, you should see the generated JSON in *jmeter.log* file.

   [image: JSR223 PostProcessor manupulate JSON]

   If you need to have it in a JMeter Variable add the next line to the end of your script:

   ```
   vars.put('newJson', newJson)
   ```

   and you will be able to access generated value as `${newJson}` where required

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)